# Accessing defrecord methods in ClojureScript Figwheel

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, figwheel

I have some code in cljc files which compiles to both Clojure and ClojureScript.

in protocols.cljc

```
(defprotocol Transformable ".." 
    (scale [this scalar] "" ) ...)
```

in pattern.cljc

```
(defrecord APattern [paths]
    Transformable
      (scale [this s] (...)) ...)
```

in another.cljc

```
(defn f [pattern] (.scale pattern (/ 1 2)) )
```

And in core.cljs

```
(another/f pattern)
```

However, I'm getting an error on the browser console

```
TypeError: pattern.scale is not a function
```

Checking the fields of pattern object in core.cljs (using js-keys) shows me that the object has something called

```
"patterning$protocols$Transformable$scale$arity$2"
```

which looks like my function. So am I just doing something wrong to access it in ClojureScript? Does . notation not work? Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Do you have this problem in both development and production mode?

Comment: I'm still only in development mode.

Answer (score 2):

Calls to protocol functions are just like calls to any other function. So your `f` function should look like:

```
(require 'protocols)
(defn f [pattern] (protocols/scale pattern (/ 1 2)) )
```

Comment: The problem I have is that I'm trying to write a library that's usable both in the browser from ClojureScript AND callable from Java. The reason I moved to defprotocol and the .notation is that I was hoping to be able to make Java-friendly APIs without having to write a wrapper. Are you saying thats not possible?

Comment: Also when I try a version of your suggestion (in the cljs (protocols/scale pattern 0.5) , it now says "p1__25094_SHARP_.scale is not a function"

Comment: The function `f` is a Clojure function so if you want to use it from Java, you are already in clojureland, so the protocols/scale is the correct way to use it. If what you want to reuse is the Pattern record from Java, then you will use the Java syntax: `new pattern.APattern("").scale("bar");` which is completely unrelated to the function `f`

Comment: Also, `(println (protocols/scale (pattern/->APattern "") ""))` works as expected both in ClojureScript and Clojure. Please share your code if you want some help finding what is wrong with your code.